# Getting Image from URL (Java)

Tags: java, image, url

I am trying to read the following image

[image]

But it is showing IIOException.

Here is the code:

```
Image image = null;
URL url = new URL("http://bks6.books.google.ca/books?id=5VTBuvfZDyoC&printsec=frontcover&img=1& zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api");
image = ImageIO.read(url);
jXImageView1.setImage(image);
```

Comment: javax.imageio.IIOException ... "Can't get input stream from URL!"

Comment: Do you blocked your application in your firewall?

Comment: No .. can easily get other images

Comment: There is a space symbol in your URL, try removing that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are getting an `HTTP 400` (Bad Request) error because there is a `space` in your URL. If you fix it (before the `zoom` parameter), you will get an `HTTP 401` error (Unauthorized).
Maybe you need some HTTP header to identify your download as a recognised browser (use the "User-Agent" header) or additional authentication parameter.

For the User-Agent example, then use the [ImageIO.read(InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream%29) using the connection inputstream:

```
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "xxxxxx");
```

Use whatever needed for `xxxxxx`

Comment: Space there is just by mistake .. Anyway how to add header information?

Comment: I have the same problem but when I add Image image = ImageIO.read(url) i get an error - Cannot resolve symbol IO

Comment: How can I find the User Agent I should use for a certain browser? I am using Chrome

Answer (score 22):

**This code worked fine for me.**

```
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.net.URL;

public class SaveImageFromUrl {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String imageUrl = "http://www.avajava.com/images/avajavalogo.jpg";
    String destinationFile = "image.jpg";

    saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);
}

public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

    byte[] b = new byte[2048];
    int length;

    while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
        os.write(b, 0, length);
    }

    is.close();
    os.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Hi. Is there a api that would return the image if I provide a website link?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612896/android-load-thumbnail-from-website-url-using-glide-picasso

Comment: try JSoup library. Here is the reference link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465586/how-can-i-download-an-image-using-jsoup

Answer (score 14):

**Try This:**

```
//urlPath = address of your picture on internet
URL url = new URL("urlPath");
BufferedImage c = ImageIO.read(url);
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(c);
jXImageView1.setImage(image);
```

Answer (score 4):

Directly calling a URL to get an image may concern with major security issues.
You need to ensure that you have sufficient rights to access that resource.
However You can use `ByteOutputStream` to read image file. This is an example (Its just an example, you need to do necessary changes as per your requirement.)

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bis = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream is = null;
try {
  is = url.openStream ();
  byte[] bytebuff = new byte[4096]; 
  int n;

  while ( (n = is.read(bytebuff)) > 0 ) {
    bis.write(bytebuff, 0, n);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```java
public class ImageComponent extends JComponent {
  private final BufferedImage img;

  public ImageComponent(URL url) throws IOException {
    img = ImageIO.read(url);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));

  }

  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), this);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final URL kitten = new URL("https://placekitten.com/g/200/300");

    final ImageComponent image = new ImageComponent(kitten);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(image));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the this class to displays an image read from a URL within a JFrame.

```
public class ShowImageFromURL {

    public static void show(String urlLocation) {
        Image image = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlLocation);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

            conn.connect();
            InputStream urlStream = conn.getInputStream();
            image = ImageIO.read(urlStream);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JLabel lblimage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            frame.getContentPane().add(lblimage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(image.getWidth(null) + 50, image.getHeight(null) + 50);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong, sorry:" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Ref : https://gist.github.com/aslamanver/92af3ac67406cfd116b7e4e177156926

Comment: How do you find the User-Agent string value for a certain browser?