# How can I set images from HTTP protect URL parsed with jsoup in different listView?

Tags: android, html, parsing, imageview, jsoup

Doing the code above I have an arraylist with url images in **objImages**

```
Element table2 = document.select("TABLE").get(1); 
                Elements asWithName  = table2.select("tr>td a[name]");
                for (Element aWithName : asWithName) {
                    String name = aWithName.attr("name");
                    hostName.add(name);
                    Element tr = aWithName.parent().parent();
                    for (Element td : tr.select("td")){
                        Element img = td.select("img").first();
                        if (img == null){
                            continue;
                        }
                    String imgRelPath = img.attr("src");
                    images.add("http://hostname.com"+imgRelPath);
                    }
                    objImages = images.toArray(); 
                }
                objHostName = hostName.toArray();
```

Fine, I have the URLs. Now I have to get the images from those URLs and put it in imageView, each image in different imageView.

I was doing with:

```
for {int i=0; i<objImages.length; i++}
    InputStream input = new java.net.URL(objImages[i]).openStream();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    ...
}
```

The problem is that **http://hostname.com/hobbit/gifs/static/green.gif** is protected by user/password (with .htaccess file).

But it doesn't work. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679916/jsoup-connection-with-basic-access-authentication) for basic authentication and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465586/how-can-i-download-an-image-using-jsoup) for downloading images with jsoup

In the end you will have something like this

```
String username = "foo";
String password = "bar";
String login = username + ":" + password;
String base64login = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(login.getBytes()));

Response resultImageResponse = Jsoup.header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64login)
                                    .connect(imageLocation).ignoreContentType(true).execute();

// output here
FileOutputStream out = (new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(outputFolder + name)));
out.write(resultImageResponse.bodyAsBytes());  // resultImageResponse.body() is where the image's contents are.
out.close();
```

Comment: I will try later and I'll give you feedback. Thanks @alkis !