# How to retrieve an image from a web server (image/png header)

Tags: java

I have a web server with a PHP script that gives me a random image stored on the server. This response is directly an image with the following header :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 20 Jan 2020 12:10:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 2099 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 20 Jan 2020 12:10:05 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 971646
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/png
```

As you can see, the server replies directly to me with a MIME png file type. Now I want to retrieve this image from a JAVA program. I already have a code that allows me to read text from an http request but how do I save an image from the web?

```
public class test {

    // one instance, reuse
    private final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
            .build();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        test obj = new test();

        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http POST request");
        obj.sendPost();

    }

    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        // form parameters
        Map<Object, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("arg", "value");

        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .POST(buildFormDataFromMap(data))
                .uri(URI.create("url_here"))
                .setHeader("User-Agent", "Java 11 HttpClient Bot") // add request header
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        // print status code
        System.out.println(response.statusCode());

        // print response body
                System.out.println(response.headers());

                try {
                    saveImage(response.body(), "path/to/file.png");
                }
                catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    public static void saveImage(String image, String destinationFile) throws IOException {     
            //What to write here ?
    }

    private static HttpRequest.BodyPublisher buildFormDataFromMap(Map<Object, Object> data) {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            if (builder.length() > 0) {
                builder.append("&");
            }
            builder.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey().toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            builder.append("=");
            builder.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue().toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                }

        return HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(builder.toString());
    }
```

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Just a 2c, but unless the server is sending the image as a Base64 Encoded string, the easiest approach would be to read the image as an array of bytes, and write that to file.

Comment: use input stream to download any file type for more refer in this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android)

Comment: Thank you very much @Nazimch you solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    try(InputStream is = url.openStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile)){

            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;

            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }

            }catch(IOException  e){
            throw e;
            }
    }
```

[Getting Image from URL (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292792/getting-image-from-url-java)

Comment: I can't use it because I need a POST request with parameters

Comment: have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.html: `// Receives the response body as an InputStream
   HttpResponse<InputStream> response = client
     .send(request, BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());` Then write the stream to a file.

Comment: Thank you very much @MarcStröbel you solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote my own Http client which is part of an Open-source Java library called MgntUtils, that allows you to read both textual and binary responses. Your code could look as follows:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8"); //set any appropriate content type (of the input if you send any information from the client to the server)
client.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer ey..."); // this is just an example of how to set any header if you need. You might not need to set any additional headers
ByteBuffer buff = client.sendHttpRequestForBinaryResponse("http://example.com/image",HttpMethod.POST, "bla bla"); //This is example of invoking method POST with some input data "bla bla", third parameter is not mandatory if you have no data to pass
ByteBuffer buff1 = client.sendHttpRequestForBinaryResponse("http://example.com/image",HttpMethod.GET); //This is an example of invoking GET method
```

I and some other people used this library, and it is simple to use and works nicely. The library is available as Maven artifacts [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) and from GitHub including sources and JavaDoc [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) JavaDoc for HttpClient class is [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html)